Graduated symbology
I have opened a delimited text file with coordinates XY defined in two columns on the file plus two other columns with data and they are represented in QGIS as a point layer.
I want to symbolize the results by graduation but when I open the the list the field I want to symbolize doesn't appear altough when I open the attribute table or try to symbolize by categories I can see that the field is there.



You can't graduate using a string field, you need to convert it to real first, using the field calculator to create a new field with the follwing expression
to_real("correlation")

Don't think that'll work, the string has a comma which I guess is meant to be a decimal point? If so that'll need to be got rid of first: to_real(replace("correlation", ',', '.'))
